# Hexo 'alt text' doesn't work

Tags: css, image, hexo

`{% img [class names] /path/to/image [width] [height] [title text [alt text]] %}`

I use 'Tag Plugins' to define the size of image，but how to define 'alt text'. I have tried many time but it dose not work. I think there should an separator between 'title text' and 'alt text'.

Comment: Please paste the code that you have tried and that didnt work. Alt is supported for img tag plugin. Code is here https://github.com/hexojs/hexo/blob/master/lib/plugins/tag/img.js

Comment: Thank you .My code is "{% img /img/zcyl/xc.png 200 290 xc xc %}",but i cann't understand the meaning of the regex,it seems like match all the string and i found it would match twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the title text in double quotes, and the alt text in single quotes within the title qualifiers... like so "Title text goes here'alt text goes here'"

Comment: No problem @kaiux. Hexo documentation is unusually lean. If the approach worked feel free to mark it as the accepted answer.